# chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension to listen to the install / uninstall / enabled / disabled events for other extensions either by using chrome web store or by other means.

I am planning to use the chrome.management module for that.

1. I had declared the permissions in the manifest.json file.

   ```
   "permissions": [
       "management"
   ],
   ```
2. I have a background.html page

   ```
   "background": {
       "page": "background.html"
   },
   ```
3. I had included the background.js as a part of the background.html page

   ```
   <html>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. And here is my background.js

   ```
   chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {
     console.log('somethingz installed...');
     printInfo(info);
     });

   chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {
     console.log('somethingz enabled...');
     printInfo(info);
   });


   chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {
     console.log('somethingz disabled...');
     printInfo(info);
   });


   function printInfo(info)
   {
     console.log("id: " ++ info.id);
     console.log("name: " ++ info.name);
     console.log("description: " ++ info.description);
     console.log("version: " ++ info.version);
     console.log("mayDisable: " ++ info.mayDisable);
     console.log("enabled: " ++ info.enabled);
     console.log("disabledReason: " ++ info.disabledReason);
     console.log("type: " ++ info.type);
     console.log("appLaunchURL: " ++ info.appLaunchURL);
     console.log("homepageUrl: " ++ info.homepageUrl );
     console.log("updateUrl: " ++ info.updateUrl  );
     console.log("offlineEnabled: " ++ info.offlineEnabled);
     console.log("optionsUrl: " ++ info.optionsUrl);
     console.log("icons: " ++ info.icons);
     console.log("permissions: " ++ info.permissions);
     console.log("hostPermissions: " ++ info.hostPermissions);
     console.log("installType: " ++ info.installType);
   }
   ```

I am trying to debug the background.html page by looking at the chrome://extensions page and I am seeing -

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and the events are not firing as expected because of this error.

Please help!! not sure what is causing the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error... May be it is something too basic, however, I am not able to catch it by looking at it for quite some time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 major problems. First you include the type of the parameters in the listeners, in this case the `ExtensionInfo`, remove that. Second, you are using 2 `+` change it to 1.
The resulting code looks like this:

```
chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(function(info) {
  console.log('somethingz installed...');
  printInfo(info);
});
```

And this

```
function printInfo(info){
  console.log("id: " + info.id);
```

As a side note, instead of manually logging every part of info, you can just do something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(info).replace(',','\n'));
```

Comment: I feel so dumb! :( Thank you very much.